# Is there a way in NextJS to show a warning of unused variables in terminal as CRA does it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS with TypeScript. Is there a way to show an unused variable warning in the terminal as CRA shows it?

So why I wanted to have this is because when there is any unused variables the build fails and each time I had to run yarn build in my local remove all of the unused variables and then again make a commit.

So this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I thought NextJS bundled ESLint already; is the issue it's not running across hot reloads?

Comment: I am on version `10.0.7` of NextJS which doesn't support Eslint by default.
The NextJS docs say [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint) it comes with version 11.
So I guess maybe I should try to update my NextJS to `11`?

Comment: Could do that, or add it manually. Personally I'd lean towards upgrading NextJS.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @DaveNewton. I just upgraded it to `11.1.2`
I was not doing it being afraid it can break something,
But it is working fine now. 
But still, I am manually running `yarn lint`. And gives the warning as below.


`./src/components/HeroSection/Card/index.tsx
19:7  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./src/components/Services/index.tsx
48:9  Error: 'a' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
`

Comment: But I guess now I can run `next lint` using `husky` and precommit to check these warnings before committing.

Comment: The purpose I have mentioned in the question, now finally after upgrading to 11.1.2 and using husky and following [this](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-automate-code-linting-in-next-js-with-eslint-husky-git-hooks/#step-3-automatically-linting-during-development) article I am able to achieve.

PS: I had to use npm 7.4.0 for the solution provided in the article.

Maybe I will answer the question myself of how I achieved the goal of avoiding the build fail.